# jQuery hidden ajax optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery('select[field]').each(function(){
    var jobj = $(this);
    var pre_field_name = jobj.attr('filtered_by');
    var parent_field_name = jobj.attr('field');
    var data_url =jobj.attr('data-url');
    var val = jobj.val();
    $('select[name='+parent_field_name+']').change(function(){
        console.log('change');
        if($(this).val()){
            console.log('ajax');
            $.get(data_url, {'pk': $(this).val()}, function(response){
                console.log('response');
                var options = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + response[i].value + '" '+  (val==response[i].value?'selected="selected"':'') +  '>' + response[i].display + '</option>';
                }
                jobj.html(options);
                jobj.change();
            })
        } else {
            jobj.html('<option value="">------</option>');
            jobj.change();
        }
    }).change();

})
```

If there are 3 elements on my page that satisfy this `jQuery('select[field]')` selector - then, in chrome logs I'll see six (doubled by `.change()` I guess) `response` log records. But in `network` tab of chrome console and in server logs, I see that there was only one request. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hidden optimization, it's a [documented](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) behavior that caches the http response,

### Cache

> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with
>   HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
>   GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of
>   requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already
>   been requested by a GET.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post your html too?

I recommend you to select your parent attributes in one jquery selector. See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GsjD7/4/)

```
$("div[parent_field_name='test'] select").change(function(){
    var data_url = 'ajaxUrl';

    console.log('ajax');
    $.get(data_url, {'pk': $(this).val()}, function(response){
        console.log('response');
    });
}).change();
```

Html:

```
<div class="parent" parent_field_name="test">
<select>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test2</option>
</select>
</div>
```